# FFmpeg change video speed with -r vs -filter and setpts

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, frame-rate

If I want to change the video speed with ffmpeg,

what exactly is the difference changing the fps:

`ffmpeg -y -r 10 -i video.mp4 video_new_fps.mp4`

or using filter and setpts:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS*3" -an video_new_fps.mp4`

It seems that with both options I can speed up or slow down the video.

So which one should be used in which case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the latter is a universal safer approach. If the input video stream uses a constant framerate, then both should result in the identical output. If the input framerate is variable, `-r` input option will mess up the timing, I presume.